# Looking for a custom filter than simulates the "Update Project" for status reporting

Tags: ms-project

I am currently working with Project Server 2013, PWA and Project 2013 Pro.  I am trying to create a dashboard, and require a planned %complete in a project that has no budget, or costs associated with it.

This means I have to create a custom filter that will mimic the Update Project button in the project status tab.

Has anyone else had to do this, or can you provide alternatives I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something similar to do this in 2010 - I assume it will work in 2013, although can't test it.

Although you don't have any budget or costs, I'm assuming that you do have a baseline with hours against it. That being the case, the following code will output the Planned % Complete (i.e. the proportion of hours you should have burnt on a given task by the status date) to field text11

```
 Option Explicit
Sub CalcBaselinePerctComplete()
Dim pj As Project
Dim t As Task
Dim TSV As TimeScaleValue
Dim TSVs As TimeScaleValues
Dim HrsValue As Double
Dim PerctValue As Integer
Set pj = ActiveProject
For Each t In pj.Tasks
    Select Case pj.StatusDate
        Case Is > t.BaselineFinish
            'If the baseline end date is in the past, then the PerctValue must be 100%
            'so no need to loop through the time scaled PerctValues
            PerctValue = 100
        Case Is < t.BaselineStart
            'If the baseline start date is in the future, then the PerctValue must be 0%
            'so no need to loop through the time scaled PerctValues
            PerctValue = 0
        Case Else
            If t.BaselineWork = 0 Then
                'if there is no baseline work, then the PerctValue must be 1005
                'otherwise we've be dividing by zero
                PerctValue = 100
            Else
                Set TSVs = t.TimeScaleData(t.Start, pj.StatusDate, pjTaskTimescaledBaselineWork, pjTimescaleDays)
                HrsValue = 0
                For Each TSV In TSVs
                    If TSV.Value <> "" Then
                        HrsValue = HrsValue + TSV.Value
                    End If
                Next TSV
                PerctValue = HrsValue / t.BaselineWork * 100
            End If
    End Select
SetValue:
t.Text11 = PerctValue & "%"
Next t
End Sub
```